# Scala Stream Off By One

Tags: scala, dictionary, stream

Can someone please explain the following output from the REPL?

I'm defining 2 (infinite) Streams that are otherwise identical in their definition except that *map* is preceded by *.* (period) in one definition and a _ _ (space) in the other.

I can see that this would cause *map* to bind differently, but what happens to the *1* in the output from the second definition?

Thanks.

```
scala> lazy val infinite: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: infinite.map(_+1)
infinite: Stream[Int] = <lazy>

scala> val l = infinite.take(10).toList.mkString(",")
l: String = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

scala> lazy val infinite2: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: infinite2 map(_+1)
infinite2: Stream[Int] = <lazy>

scala> val l2 = infinite2.take(10).toList.mkString(",")
l2: String = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's about [method associativity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162924). This:

```
1 #:: infinite.map(_+1)
```

is quite straightforward while this:

```
1 #:: infinite2 map(_+1)
```

is interpreted by the compiler as:

```
(1 #:: infinite2) map(_+1)
```

`1 #:: infinite2` is your desired stream, but before you return it, you apply lazy transformation adding one to every item. This explains why `1` never appears as a result - after transformation it becomes `2`.

For more details see: [Operator precedence in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922347). Since `#` is not a special character, it is treated equally with `map`, thus methods are evaluated from left to right.

Comment: @BillBarrington: No problem. Please accept/upvote this or the other answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

In the infinite2 case, what you've expressed is equivalent to the following:

```
lazy val infinite2: Stream[Int] = (1 #:: infinite2) map(_ + 1)
```

Since the stream starts with 1, the map will add 1 to the first element.