# Why do you use concat operator backward in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, operators

In scala `repl`

```
scala> List(1) :: 2
<console>:8: error: value :: is not a member of Int
          List(1) :: 2
```

but

```
scala> 2 :: List(1);
res4: List[Int] = List(2, 1)
```

This is counter intuitive since if infix operators are read left to right, the above line can be translate to

```
List(1) :: 2
List(1).::(2)
```

and

```
2 :: List(1)
2.::(List(1))
```

I would imagine an `Int` does not have method `::` while a `List` does. Am I assuming something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What good are right-associative methods in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162924/what-good-are-right-associative-methods-in-scala)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is counter intuitive since if infix operators are read left to
>   right

If you  think about it, logically, it makes much sense. The `::` (cons) operator *prepends* the value to the beginning of the list, it doesn't *append* it to the end of the list. When you think about it like that, the fact that the `::` operator is right associative makes sense, as it is sticking an element to the beginning of the `List`:

```
scala> 4 :: List(3,2,1)
res1: List[Int] = List(4, 3, 2, 1)
```

The internal implementation is rather simple:

```
def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] =
  new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)
```

`List` is internally implemented as a LinkedList which contains a head which is the first element in the collection, and a list of remaining elements which are the tail. That is why prepending the element is much cheaper than appending it, as it would require an O(n) traversal of the internal list in order to copy the elements, plus appending of the new value.

Although expensive, you can still do it using the `:+` operator, which is *left associative*:

```
scala> List(1,2,3) :+ 4
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

Scala operators that end in `:` are right-associative. So, in your example, you are trying to apply the `::` operator to an `Int`.

Also, `List` structures are immutable in Scala, so appending to the end of a list is quite expensive; prepending a value to the beginning of a list is very cheap.