# Why not have Lists build the other way around and have them append elements?

Tags: scala, language-design

Since in Scala lists are actually build like (here for `List(1,2,3)`) this:

```
[ 1 , [ 2, [ 3 , Nill ] ] ]          // (pseudo-code)
```

it is more efficient to pretend new elements and that is why `::` is right associative (all explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1162980/4533188) - to be better readable (here `1 :: 2 :: 3`). That answers my question, why it's good to have right association in the first place. But why didn't the designers of Lists simply construct them like

```
[ Nill , [ 3, [ 2 , 1 ] ] ]          // (pseudo-code)
```

internally and use conventional left association?

Here in a graphic what my pseudo-code is supposed to mean (since it does not show the "links" of the linked list):

[image]

Comment: Because traversing the list in front-to-back order would have to either be O(n²) or build an intermediate `reverse` of the list.

Comment: Your example is invalid (type-wise). Did you mean `[[[Nill, 3], 2], 1]`?

Comment: No, I think I meant, what I wrote. In fact it is an abbreviation, since it should be a tree-like structure.

Comment: @Bergi: I added a graphic.

Comment: @Make42: But what would the type of `Cons` (`::`) be? The first instance contains two lists (`Nill` and the reference), the second contains a number and a list, and the third contains two numbers. That can't work. If you really meant a tree, then you should draw one, with proper nodes and leafs.

Comment: @Bergi: They way I drew the structure, is the way Martin Odersky drew it in one of his lectures. I am not an expert on the topic - that is how he described it.

Comment: @Make42: The first one, yes. The second one, no.

Comment: Ok, true, you're right.

Comment: @Bergi: You asked what its type would be. Isn't `Nil` (like `Nothing`) one of those classes that inherit from every class? If so there would not be an issue of the type.

Comment: @Make42: No, it is an instance of `List[Nothing]` (so that it can be the last part of every list regardless of its type).

Answer (score 2):

Because an append-list wouldn't be immutable (or you'd have to copy it in its entirety on each change).

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list for mre.