# Right associative with operator :

Tags: scala

I can merge two lists as follow together:

```
List(1,2,3) ::: List(4,5,6)
```

and the result is:

```
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

the operator `:::` is right associative, what does it mean?

In math, right associative is:

```
5 + ( 5 - ( 2 * 3 ) )
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162924/what-good-are-right-associative-methods-in-scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right associative means the operator (in our case, the `:::` method) is applied on the right operand while using the left operand as the argument. This means that the actual method invocation is done like this:

```
List(4,5,6).:::(List(1,2,3))
```

Since `:::` *prepends* the list, the result is `List(1,2,3,4,5,6)`.

Answer (score 1):

In the most general sense, [right-associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) means that if you don't put any parentheses, they will be assumed to be on the right:

```
a ::: b ::: c == a ::: (b ::: c)
```

whereas left-associative operators (such as `+`) would have

```
a + b + c == (a + b) + c
```

However, according to the [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (6.12.3 Infix Operations),

> A left-associative binary operation `e1 op e2` is interpreted as `e1.op(e2)`. If op is rightassociative,
>   the same operation is interpreted as `{ val x=e1; e2.op(x ) }`, where
>   `x` is a fresh name.

So right-associative operators in scala are considered as methods of their right operand with their left operand as parameter (as explained in @Yuval's answer).