# Ommiting parenthesis in adding elements to List

Tags: scala, list

I'm trying to add element to a `List[String]` while omitting annoying parenthesis. I tried this:

```
object Main extends App {
    val l = List("fds")
    val xs1: List[String] = l.+:("123")  // ok
    val xs2: List[String] = l +: "123"   // compile-error
}
```

[***DEMO***](https://ideone.com/kS7GMH)

Why is omitting parenthesis causing compile-error? These assignments look the same to me. What is the difference?

Comment: l.+:("123") is equivalent to "123" +: l not to l +: "123"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's happening because of right associative methods.

```
scala> val l = List("abc")
l: List[String] = List(abc)

scala> "efg" +: l
res3: List[String] = List(efg, abc)
```

Read more here [What good are right-associative methods in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162924/what-good-are-right-associative-methods-in-scala)

### Error case

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)


scala> 4 +: l 
res1: List[Int] = List(4, 1, 2, 3)

scala> l +: 1
<console>:13: error: value +: is not a member of Int
       l +: 1
     ^
```

Because `+:` is right associative. Method `+:` is getting invoked on Int instead of list

In order to make it work we can explicitly invoke method on list without the special operator syntax

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.+:(1)
res4: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 3)
```

Above case works because its normal method invocation.